# Efficient drawing with DrawingGroup

Tags: c#, wpf, drawing

How to draw with DrawingGroup partially?

Here is what I want to do. I want to draw some initial elements first.

```
private readonly DrawingGroup _backingStore = new DrawingGroup();

protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
{
    base.OnRender(dc);
    InitialRender();
    dc.DrawDrawing(_backingStore);
}

private void InitialRender()
{
    var dc = _backingStore.Open();
    // draw with draw context.
    _backingStore.Close();
}
```

Initial render works fine. now when collection source changes, I want to draw more elements on existing drawings.

The problem is that when I Open Drawing group to get drawing context, everything gets cleared (and only new drawings remain).

```
private void ValueOnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
{
    Render(args.NewItems);
}

private void Render(IList newItems)
{
    var dc = _backingStore.Open(); // how to avoid clearing previous items?
    // draw more stuff
    dc.Close();
}
```

Comment: Did you try to simply add (or insert) a new Drawing to the Children collection of the DrawingGroup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Clemens for his comment, I have to use `_backingStore.Append();` instead in order to keep previous drawings.